# copying pdf file to clipboard with VBA

Tags: excel, pdf, vba, clipboard

I have an excel macro which creates a PDF to file of an excel document.

I then need to put a copy of the document to the clipboard, so users can then paste to emails, etc without having to go and attach the file.

I have tried to create an email with an attachment of the PDF which runs well, however I am looking for a "faster" option (copying to clipbpoard automatically)

Can this be done with VBA ?

Answer (score 0):

Check out my answer at ["Paste" string variable in excel VBA instead of the contents of clipboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726310/paste-string-variable-in-excel-vba-instead-of-the-contents-of-clipboard/4730289#4730289)

Maybe it could lead you in the right direction.

Comment: Please add here the relevant part of your code where you show how to insert the pdf on the clipboard. I can't find it.

Comment: Sorry, belisarius! You didn't find it cause there isn't such a code the way you stated. The code I posted in that answer should be taken as a possible clue to the solution, not the solution itself. Although, I cannot guarantee it won't be a dead lock. That code was something I was playing with a long time ago and have to do with copy and paste operations based on Windows API (probably you noticed that).

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little older but looking for the same answer, I finally found one I wanted to link here (because this question here still comes up first in the search engine).
Look here to find a working solution:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e624729a-e8bd-4d16-867f-6bd48000bbaa/copy-file-into-clipboard?forum=isvvba